# В каком значении употреблено слово (вправе) в тексте документа?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Добрый День!

Прошу дать толкование положений текста (выделено цветом) документа (Устава ООО)для установления того, какие варианты понимания этих положений возможны в современном дискурсе;

1) Каково значение выделенного предложения?  а)как обязанность поступать только таким образом (т.е. ... обязан продавать по цене не выше номинальной стоимости.)? ;

> б) имеет право (разрешающее) поступать таким образом и иначе, по
>   своему   усмотрению (т.е. ... имеет право продавать по цене не выше
>   номинальной   стоимости, но так же имеет право  продавать и по другой
>   стоимости).

2) В каком значении употреблено слово (вправе) в тексте документа? а) как обязанность поступать только таким образом; б) разрешающее поступать таким образом и иначе, по своему усмотрению

Статья  16. Переход доли участника в уставном капитале общества к другим участникам и третьим лицам.
1.Участник общества вправе продавать свою долю или часть доли в уставном капитале общества одному или нескольким участникам данного общества, по цене не выше номинальной стоимости принадлежащей ему доли или части доли. 
2.      Участник общества не вправе продавать или осуществлять отчуждение иным образом своей доли или части доли в уставном капитале общества третьим лицам.
3.      Сделка, направленная на отчуждение доли или части доли в уставном капитале общества, подлежит нотариальному удостоверению. Несоблюдение нотариальной формы указанной сделки влечет за собой ее недействительность.
Доля или часть доли в уставном капитале общества переходит к ее приобретателю с момента нотариального удостоверения сделки, направленной на отчуждение доли или части доли в уставном капитале общества либо в случаях, не требующих нотариального удостоверения, с момента внесения в единый государственный реестр юридических лиц соответствующих изменений на основании правоустанавливающих документов.
4. Доли в уставном капитале общества переходят к наследникам Участника. До принятия наследником умершего участника общества наследства права умершего участника общества осуществляются, а его обязанности исполняются лицом, указанным в завещании, а при отсутствии такого лица управляющим, назначенным нотариусом.

Comment: Я бы ответил, но все это так давно было... Если кратко, то речь идет об ограничительном праве. "Имеет право продать... (но только) по цене не выше...".

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, всё ясно: Если хочешь, можешь продать свою долю, но только по цене не выше номинальной стоимости и только участникам этого общества, а не третьим лицам. Не вправе дарить кому-то, только продать другому члену общества, чтобы количество долей ООО не уменьшалось, всё осталось внутри. И спекулировать, завышать цену нельзя.

Comment: Не совсем ясно...Спасибо за Вашу точку зрения.